# echo custom post type ID from custom post title WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

if been searching for hours :-( Hope anyone can help me.

I'm in a custom post type called "grhdogs". There I need to fetch the current page title of that page and search with that title in another custom post type called "slideshow" and echo (as string) the page ID of the matching pagetitle in "slideshow".

The background is that in both custom post types are always matching page titles. I have to bring them together because "grhdogs" is a post and "slideshow" is the matching slideshow that I want to display in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some thing like this.

```
<?php
//get the current title of the page
$postTitle = get_the_title(); 

//search for similer post in db table
$postID = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE   post_type='slideshow' AND post_title = %s",$postTitle));

//print id
 echo $postID;  

//or use get_post($post_id) to get whatever you want
$getCustomPost = get_post($postID);
echo $getCustomPost->id;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm almost there. I only need to echo the post ID of the matching post in 'slideshow'. So I need to echo the "the_ID();" of the result of $postID.

Comment: first check do the print_r($postID) to check your id than print it like echo $getCustomPost->id or echo $getCustomPost->ID;

Comment: Like so?

$getCustomPost = print_r($postID);
echo $getCustomPost->ID;

Comment: No print_r($postID) will just print the entire object/array. print_r is just to check your values. You can't print the value with print_r. You have to use echo $getCustomPost->id to print the id.

Comment: I have modified my code to print the id. if you just need the id than delete the last 2 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, this is the code I used in the end and worked. Your snippet missed an AND. Thanks Ram!